# Creating job dynamically in Quartz + Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to register jobs/trigger dynamically. The scenario is i have database which have all the job configurations like job start time. So i'm trying to get register this jobs by run time. Whenever i run register the job, it gives me following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/hello/QuartzFactory.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: null [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.hello.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: null
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:254) ~[spring-context-support-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:512) ~[spring-context-support-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Code: QuartzFactory

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();

        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

     @Autowired
        private QuartzConfiguration quartzConfiguration;

     @Bean
        public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {

            quartzConfiguration.setExpression("0/10 * * * * ?");
            CronTriggerFactoryBean data = quartzConfiguration.cronTriggerFactoryBean();

            SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
            scheduler.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
            scheduler.setTriggers(data.getObject());
            return scheduler;
        }
}
```

**QuartzConfiguration**

```
@Component
@ComponentScan("com.hello") 
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    public String getExpression() {
        return expression;
    }

    public void setExpression(String expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    private String expression;


    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean(){
        JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factory.setJobClass(SampleJob.class);
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("name", "RAM");
        map.put(MyJobTwo.COUNT, 1);
        factory.setJobDataAsMap(map);
        factory.setGroup("mygroup");
        factory.setName("myjob");
        return factory;
    }

    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(){
        CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        stFactory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
        stFactory.setName("mytrigger");
        stFactory.setGroup("mygroup");
        stFactory.setCronExpression(expression); //0/10 * * * * ?
        return stFactory;
    }
```

Comment: any update on that?  as I have the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the method afterPropertiesSet() on both factories.

use factory.afterPropertiesSet() and stFactory.afterPropertiesSet() after you set your properties. You will need to set a name for the Trigger Factory as well.

When you call getObject you receive null if you doesn't call this method.

OR

Annotate the both methods on QuartzConfiguration with @Bean to call automatically the afterPropertiesSet method.